# Passing SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES object via a named pipe

Tags: c++, winapi, serialization

I have two processes communicating over a named pipe.

One of them (let's call it process A) makes use of the `CreateProcessW` function by passing a bunch of parameters. I'm trying to send these parameters to process B.

How do I send objects of type `LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` from A to B using a named pipe? It's a pointer to a structure, which in turn has a pointer to another structure.

How do I go about this, do I write every object onto the pipe, or do I try to serialize the struct using a library like Boost? Or is there another way to handle such structures?

Comment: You might take a look at (ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/sddl/nf-sddl-convertsecuritydescriptortostringsecuritydescriptorw]

Comment: Security attributes are basically security descriptors. You'll have to do the work by yourself (don't use automatic serialization) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/security-descriptor-string-format

Comment: Do appreicate that a SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES object won't be valid in another process, even if you marshal its contents to that other process.

Comment: You could use [`GetSecurityInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-getsecurityinfo) + [`SetSecurityInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-setsecurityinfo) to get the `SECURITY_INFORMATION` of process A, then set B(You'll need `SE_SECURITY_NAME` privilege for setting SACL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comment, you could pass the Security Descriptor String Format to another process by using [`ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sddl/nf-sddl-convertsecuritydescriptortostringsecuritydescriptora) in process A and convert back with [`ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sddl/nf-sddl-convertstringsecuritydescriptortosecuritydescriptora) in process B:

```
    LPWSTR StringSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    ULONG Len = 0;
    SECURITY_INFORMATION flag; //set flag = whatever your want to convert into string format and send to process B
    ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptorW(ppSecurityDescriptor, SDDL_REVISION_1, flag,&StringSecurityDescriptor, &Len);
    WriteFile(hPipe, StringSecurityDescriptor, Len*sizeof(WCHAR), &dwritten, NULL);
    LocalFree(StringSecurityDescriptor);
```

And if the Security Descriptor is [Self-Relative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/absolute-and-self-relative-security-descriptors):

> a security descriptor stores a `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR` structure and
>   associated security information in a contiguous block of memory.
>
> a security descriptor always begins with a `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR`
>   structure, but the other components of the security descriptor can
>   follow the structure in any order. Instead of using memory addresses,
>   the security descriptor's components are identified by offsets from
>   the beginning of the descriptor. This format is useful when a security
>   descriptor must be stored on disk, transmitted by means of a
>   communications protocol, or copied in memory.

Or use [`MakeSelfRelativeSD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-makeselfrelativesd) to create a security descriptor in self-relative format from absolute format as a template.

In addition, you could also use [`SetSecurityInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-setsecurityinfo) to set another process' security information.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this and post the response.